# How to delay map within a component until ajax call is complete

Tags: ajax, reactjs, components, fetch, lifecycle

I have an ajax call within my App as follows:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/',{method: 'GET', mode: 'cors'})
    .then(
      (results) => results.json()
      )
    .then(
      data => this.setState(data)
      )
    .then(
      () => console.log(this.state)
      )
    .catch(
      err => console.log(err))
  }
```

The console.log prints twice; once with the state "undefined" then again when the ajax call is completed. The problem is that the component which uses the data from the ajax call;

```
componentDidMount(){
        const allProducts = this.props.products.map((val, ind) => 
            <div className="Product"><Product {...val} handleClick={this.props.handleClick} key={ind}/></div>
        );
      }
```

...is mapping before the data comes back so I hit an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Sorry if this is something too basic for this forum. It's probably something straightforward which I have forgotten!!

Comment: You are setting the data in the state, but while rendering, you are using the props. I am sorry but I am unable to connect the dots. Something is missing here. Can you provide a git repo or a codesandbox? It'll be easier for us.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to render your ajax data inside render.
set the state in the constructor to null, this would not give you the problem of 
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.*
 class SomeClass extends React.Component {

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { products: null };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/', { method: 'GET', mode: 'cors' })
            .then(
            (results) => results.json()
            )
            .then(
            data => this.setState(data)
            )
            .then(
            () => console.log(this.state)
            )
            .catch(
            err => console.log(err))
    }         



    render() {

        if (this.state.products == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (<span>{
            this.state.products.map((val, ind) =>
                <div className="Product"><Product {...val} handleClick={this.props.handleClick} key={ind} /></div>
            )
        }</span>);
    }
}
```